# Data Property to Hold Index of Array Object during Mouse Over Vuejs

Tags: html, vue.js

I've used list rendering to create a menu with items from an array. I'm now trying to create a new data property which holds the index of the array item when the item of the menu is mouse-overed but I'm not sure of how to do it. Here's what I've tried:

HTML:

```
 <header>
        <nav class="pure-menu pure-menu-horizontal">
            <ul id="topmenu" class="pure-menu-list">
                <li v-for="item in topmenu" class="pure-menu-item">
                <a v-bind:href="item.url" v-on:mouseover="mouseOver" class="pure-menu-link">{{ item.title }}</a></li>
                    <li v-for="item in topmenu.submenus" class="pure-menu-item">
                    <a v-bind:href="item.url" class="pure-menu-link">{{ item.title }}</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="pure-menu">
                <ul id="submenu" class="pure-menu-list">

                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

JS:

```
var vueinst = new Vue({
el: '#vuemain',
data: {
topmenuitem : 0,
topmenuhover : false,
topmenu: [
    { title:'Home', url:'/', submenus: [] },
    { title:'About', url:'/about', 
        submenus: [
            { title:'Who we are',   url:'/about#us' },
            { title:'What we do',   url:'/about#store' },
            { title:'Our range',     url:'/about#range' }
        ]
    },
    { title:'Contact Us',   url:'/contact', 
        submenus: [
            { title:'Information',   url:'/contact#info' },
            { title:'Returns',   url:'/contact#return' },
            { title:'Locate Us',     url:'/contact#locate' }
        ]
    }
    ]
 },
 methods: {
mouseOver: function(){
  this.topmenuitem = this.topmenu.index;
}
}
});
```

I'm pretty new to web developing, please help me with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your html pass the index of the current item to the `mouseOver` function like the following:

```
<header>
    <nav class="pure-menu pure-menu-horizontal">
        <ul id="topmenu" class="pure-menu-list">
            <li v-for="item in topmenu" :key="item.index" class="pure-menu-item">
            <a v-bind:href="item.url" v-on:mouseover="mouseOver(item.index)" class="pure-menu-link">{{ item.title }}</a></li>
                <li v-for="item in topmenu.submenus" class="pure-menu-item">
                <a v-bind:href="item.url" class="pure-menu-link">{{ item.title }}</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="pure-menu">
            <ul id="submenu" class="pure-menu-list">

            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

And you should bind key in the `v-for` like `:key="item.index"`. And then in your `mouseOver` function accept the index of the item as a parameter and push the element on that index into your new array ass follows.

```
mouseOver: function(index){
    this.topmenuitem.push(index);
}
```

This way you could get the index of all items hovered on.